# Changing the Git LFS Directory -- And Storing on NFS Mount?

Tags: git, gitlab

I can't find anything in the documentation about changing *where* LFS is storing binary files on the repository.  I'm running the latest GitLab.

The .lsconfig file does not mention a parameter for changing the location. https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn

Additionally:  Would there be any caveats to using an NFS mount as the LFS store?

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer: In /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb there is a `gitlab_rails['lfs_storage_path'] = "/mnt/storage/lfs-objects"` line that you can uncomment and edit.

Still would like to know about NFS though.